# How to specify DNS servers for all LAN machines in OpenWrt 18.x?

Tags: networking, router, dns, lan, openwrt

I would like my OpenWrt 18.x router to:

- not to handle DNS resolution requests by itself
- to forward my chosen DNS provider's servers to the machines on LAN

---

History:

Yesterday I found that I have the DNS servers specified in section **Interfaces - WAN**, there is a section for it called **Use custom DNS servers**, which sounded to me awkwardly. (Why would I want to resolve DNS requests at WAN interface?)

So, my first step was to delete those settings in WAN and move it to section **Interfaces - LAN**, there is the same section called again **Use custom DNS servers**, which I thought was it. Well, maybe it was just a better place for it than WAN, ... definitely, but **the router DHCP'd my LAN machines with the router address**, so still no change in my desire.

---

How to specify DNS servers for all LAN machines in OpenWrt 18.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I was at least in the right interface,... that's it, I would not make this up without a lot of searches.

The whole path to it is:

Network ⟹ Interfaces ⟹ LAN ⟹ DHCP Server ⟹ Advanced Settings ⟹ DHCP-Options:

here you can specify your own DNS servers with **6,** prefix like this:

```
6,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

if you are a fan of **Google** <sup>(spying on you)</sup>, or for example **OpenDNS** if you want to be free:

```
6,208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220
```

The *magical* code 6 comes from [this page](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/bootp/options.htm), but it is actually hinted I quote:

> Define additional DHCP options, for example "6,192.168.2.1,192.168.2.2" which advertises different DNS servers to clients.

---